# cant install requirment python package in virtual environment in another machine

Tags: python

I have created a requirement file from a virtual environment in my laptop machine,
when **i want to use it and install package in another machine** in create virtual environment , I give an error about cant have a such directory file(in general)
how can i solve this error in general environment(use different version in different environment?

Comment: Can you please post the error and the commands that you're using?

Answer (score 0):

On your second machine (Where you want to install requirements.txt)

1. Install virtual environment package using this command:

   `pip install virtualenv`
2. Create a virtual environment:

   `virtualenv venv`

Note: The above command will create virtual environment in your current directory with folder named "venv" (You can use any name).

3. Activate your virtual environment:

Linux/Mac: `source venv/bin/activate`

Windows: `venv\bin\activate`

4. Install requirements.txt

   `pip install -r /path/to/requirements.txt`

Comment: You don't necessarily need to install `virtualenv`; [`venv` is part of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Comment: @AKX You're right, recently I followed this whole procedure on a new machine and it worked perfectly so just shared the working method.